# call specific name of views from module

Tags: 7, forms

Below code changes the all quantity label to none. i am trying to change quantity field label for specific views block for ubercart3. (so in product node, quantity labeled as quantity and in product views block, quantity field is not labeled.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if(strpos($form_id, 'uc_product_add_to_cart') !== FALSE){
    $form['qty']['#title'] = t('');
  }
}
```

How to call specific views from module? or is this something i should do in views template?
i tried the below code and qty label doesn't change.

```
if(strpos($form_id, 'uc_product_add_to_cart') !== FALSE){
  $view = $form_state['view'];
  if ($view->name == 'my_view_machine_name') {
    $form['qty']['#title'] = t('');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to get a name of current view in form alter function, which is not related to this view - this form is just located on the same page.

Use [views_get_current_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_current_view/7) to get current view is currently in use: `$view = views_get_current_view();`

If there is no view is currently is use, views_get_current_view() will return NULL, so we need to add additional condition: `if ($view)`

```
if (strpos($form_id, 'uc_product_add_to_cart') !== FALSE) {
  $view = views_get_current_view();
  if ($view && $view->name == 'my_view_machine_name') {
    $form['qty']['#title'] = t('');
  }
}
```

Comment: `views_get_current_view();` works but it gives notice 'Trying to get property of non-object' at  $view = views_get_current_view(); in product node page without views block.

Comment: I updated the answer: additional check if (isset($view))

Comment: i learned a lot from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace 'my_view_machine_name' with your actual view machine name.

To get view machine name, you can edit your view, and in the URL you will see it: *admin/structure/views/view/**machine_name**/edit*

Comment: i did replace it with my view machine name. looks like my question is not clear. to get node type, i can use `$node = node_load(arg(1));
$node =$node->type;` what do i use to get view name? `$view = $form_state['view'];` doesn't load the view name.

Comment: i get Undefined variable warning. this is not the proper way.

Comment: That's odd... there should be a view object in $form_state.
Try this:
`if (strpos($form['#id'], 'your-view-machine-name')) {
    $form['qty']['#title'] = t('');
  }`
Don't forget to replace underscores with dashes in a view machine name, if any.

Comment: I understood what you mean, added another answer.